# ¿Cuál sería el tipo de dato para almacenar una huella dactilar?

Tags: sql-server, base-de-datos

Estoy diseñando una base de datos para una aplicación biométrica y nesecito saber qué tipo de dato utilizar para el campo donde se almacenara el template de la huella dactilar.

Comment: Que es un templete de huella dactilar? un archivo vectorial? un bitmap? un hash? Dependiendo de eso podrían ser la respuestas

Comment: TEMPLATE varbinary(MAX) encontre q este es el correcto...eso responde tu Pregunta ?

Comment: Un VARBINARY(MAX)  para guardar cualquier BLOB (binary large objects) te va a servir. Más allá que no se suele recomendar guardar objetos físicos como archivos dentro de la base de datos, pero eso es otro tema.

Comment: Es verdad lo de los objetos fisicos ...pero acuerdate q debo comparar en algun momento hacer match entre una q se lee y una q este guardada...Como lo haria si no fuese asi ??

Comment: Por empezar entiendo que es peligroso guardar la digitalización de una huella dactilar, piensa si eventualmente la base es comprometida. No conozco mucho del tema, pero sé que se suele usar para estos casos unos HASHES especiales dónde imagenes similares generan HASHES parecidos, por ej: http://www.phash.org/

Answer (score 3):

Quizá llego algo tarde para dar la respuesta,  ya que como tú mismo has aclarado, varbinary es la opción que mejor se adapta, pero me gustaría aclarar que guardar los datos de la huella dactilar en plano, es una práctica poco recomendable. Diría que incluso puede ser delito si la BD se ve comprometida.

Trátala como si fuera una contraseña más. Guarda el hash por ejemplo y podrás compararla Igual; como un simple proceso de acceso a una web. Con la ventaja de que de este modo la información no estará en plano.

Suerte con el proyecto.

Comment: Entonces entiendo que lo mejor seria guardar en un campo de tipo VarChar()  ??

Comment: Lo que almacenarías en la base de datos sería el resultado de aplicar la función de hash a los datos biométricos que obtengas de la huella.  Para comprobar si es la misma huella simplemente le aplicas el hash a la introducida y lo comparas con la almacenada. Así evitas almacenar información en plano de la huella.

Comment: Y se me olvidaba @EfrainMejiasC lo más importante, el tipo de dato que debes emplear es **binary**, ya que la función de hash siempre te va a devolver el mismo número de bytes para el mismo tipo de hash (MD5, SHA256, etc.). [Aquí](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/binary-and-varbinary-transact-sql), en la documentación oficial más información sobre este último punto.